# Spark skins : blue drop shadow on focus

Tags: apache-flex

I'm currently experimenting flex 4 skinning. I successfully skinned most of the components i need for my application, but i can't find a way to avoid this damn blue drop shadow which is displayed when u'r focused on a textfield or a combobox.

If anyone has a hint on this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the 'focusSkin' much like you set the skinClass. There's a great example here:

http://flexponential.com/2010/01/24/custom-focusskin-for-spark-components-in-flex-4/